# How to get java.io.file length using expression language

Tags: java, jsp, el

I have a jsp page and I am using Expression Language to access the name property of a java.io.File object:

```
<c:out value="${file.name}" />
```

This is working fine because the java.io.File object has a method, called getName().

What I really want to do next is to get the length of my file. As you can imagine, I tried the following:

```
<c:out value="${file.length}" />
```

This DOES NOT work, becasue the java.io.File object DOES NOT have a method called getLength(). Instead, it has a method called length(), which is incompatible with the way Expression Language works. Very annoying!

Does anyone know how I can use Expression Language and actually get the length of my file?

Thanks!

Comment: Typically, you wrap `java.io.File` with a custom class that does provide those methods.

Comment: Can't you use `Files.readAttributes(thePath, BasicFileAttributes.class).size()`?

Comment: Hi Sotirios, thanks for replying! Yeah, I pretty much figured that I'd have to wrap java.io.File. I just wondered if there were any other options open to me. Thanks again for the reply.